# My Android app doesnt disappear from "Active Applications" list like others

Tags: java, android

If I exit my app in the usual way by pressing the back button from the Main Activity it remains in the "Active Applications" list (Hold down home button, press left icon, first tab).

I have noticed that other applications do not seem to do this. Gmail for example disappears from the Active Applications list when you press the back button and go back to the home screen. What is the Gmail app doing that my app isnt?

All the apps always remain in the recent apps list (long press home button), but its just mine that seems to remain in the "Active Applications" list.

I have users contacting me saying that my app is using up their system resources as it is appearing in this Active Applications list, and none of their other apps seem to do this.

Currently I am doing this in my main activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

How can I fix this? Am I not shutting the app down properly?

Comment: `I exit my app in the usual way` - You apparently do not understand how Android works.

Comment: OK, OK, I've read the pages and pages of discussion about how android you never actually close an app, and it controls the life cycle for you, and you never give users exit buttons etc etc. I just worded it clumsily.

Comment: And the reason you think removing entry from recents makes sense is...?

Comment: It's not just your wording that it in conflict with android design, **your goal itself is mistaken**.  (As, apparently are your users - or worse, they may be victims of scam monitor apps that spread unfounded alarmism)

Comment: I've learnt a lot already. I realised now that my whole question was flawed because I was accidentally creating a second instance of the Main Activity when coming back from another activity. I've fixed than problem, and it has in turn solved this - i.e. I don't need to override onBackPressed at all! Just writing it down has helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can try calling

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that almost works perfectly! It does remove the app from the Active Applications List, but when I press the back button the first time it just seems to close down the main activity, and then restart it again, so there is a weird refresh effect on the screen. Then when I press back again, it finally exits the app...

Comment: Sorry I've just realised I'm creating a second instance of the Activity somehow...

Comment: That's what `onBackPressed()` does by default.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of moveTaskToBack:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html 
Moves the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack. Meaning activity is running still, just in the back of all the activities in your app. If you only have one activity, I'm sure you can guess what that means.

Your `onBackPressed()` isn't going to kill the app. If you wanted to do that try:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works as well just like ksarmalkar's answer. I just need to solve why I'm creating two instances of Main Activity!

Comment: An override that does nothing but call super is totally pointless.